# How to add specific start time to google sheets map duration script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been running this script in google sheets to find the transit time between location A and location B. It works well but it only finds the time at that moment. I'd like to be able to adjust for whatever time I'd like. For example how long does it take to get from A to B at 7:30 AM on saturday.

```
const GOOGLEMAPS_DURATION = (origin, destination, mode = 'driving') => {
  const { routes: [data] = [] } = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
    .setOrigin(origin)
    .setDestination(destination)
    .setMode(mode)
    .getDirections();
  if (!data) {
    throw new Error('No route found!');
  }
  const { legs: [{ duration: { text: time } } = {}] = [] } = data;
  return time;
};
```

Any help is appreciated.

I tried chatgbt but only got errors or blank cells.

Comment: Can I ask you about the relationship between `For example how long does it take to get from A to B at 7:30 AM on saturday.` and your showing script?

Comment: The script returns a duration if given address a and address b. The problem is that the duration is for that specific time. So if I were to go into google maps right now and enter those addresses that's the time I would get. I would like it to return a different time than right now.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your expected result. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Yes, no worries I'll try and phrase it differently. The current code I have above works. It's a script for google sheets and when I use the command =GOOGLEMAPS_DURATION(A2, B2, "transit") it returns the transit time for those two locations. Unforutently, it doesn't give the transit time for a specific time. I'd like to be able to have the time duration for 7:30 AM rather than at the time that I'm inputting my numbers in. If you go on google maps, you can find a little button that says "depart at" and you can choose a time.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing discussion and answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking for is the `setDepart` method to define another time of departure than right now.

You can find the [documention here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/direction-finder#setdeparttime).

```
const GOOGLEMAPS_DURATION = (origin, destination, mode = 'driving') => {
  const { routes: [data] = [] } = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
    .setOrigin(origin)
    .setDestination(destination)
    .setDepart(new Date()) // change the date here
    .setMode(mode)
    .getDirections();
  if (!data) {
    throw new Error('No route found!');
  }
  const { legs: [{ duration: { text: time } } = {}] = [] } = data;
  return time;
};
```

From my tests:

1. the depart time must be in the future
2. it seems not to change much, the API always returns the same thing for my cases

The Apps Script Direction service is using the old Google Maps Direction API, you might have better luck by implementing HTTP calls to the [Routes API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes) (but so you will have to create a GCP project, with a valid billing account and so on).

Comment: Do you know how to implement routes API? I have a trial to google maps api and have the routes api as well. I tried using the code you gave me and setting a time in the future wasn't that accurate. I can check it with google maps and usually it's off, I don't even know if it's working properly though.

Comment: I do but I don't have examples to provide. Basically it's making authentified calls to this endpoint (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/reference/rest/v2/TopLevel/computeRoutes#http-request) so first you need to retrieve an access token (Oauth2 process) then make the call with `UrlFetch`, decode the JSON response...